# Выпадающее меню

Tags: html, css

Как в этом меню можно добавить пункты?

Например, чтобы открывались 3, 4 пункт при наведении мыши. Какие свойства нужно прописать в CSS и куда добавить пункты.

```
<ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Квартиры</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Новостройки</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Нежилые помещения</span></a></li>
    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Дома и коттеджи</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста не дублируйте [вопросы][1].


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/324016/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-%D0%B2-css

Answer (score 2):

В интернете поэтому вопросу материалов огромное количество. Например: http://jsfiddle.net/XGzmh/

```css
/*Обнуляем отступы*/
ul, li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;   
}
 
/*Задаём параметры блока, содержащего основное меню*/
#menu {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:50px;         
}
 
/*Задаём стили для разделов нашего меню*/
#menu > li {
    display:inline-block;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
}
 
/*Стили для скрытого выпадающего меню*/
#menu > li > ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    display:none;   
}
 
/*Делаем скрытую часть видимой*/
#menu > li:hover > ul {
    display:block;  
}
```

```html
 <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Раздел1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Раздел2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Разде3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел7</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>       
</ul>
```